# Need to replace 13 blank spaces from 1 very long line of text file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, str-replace

I have a file (1.8 Mb) that has 1 single (very long) row of text. The values on that row are generally separated by 13 blank spaces. What I am trying to do is to replace these 13 blank spaces with a pipe | delimiter so that I can process this text file using SSIS.

So far, I have had no success in programmatically processing this file using a batch file.

I have tried using the below code that I got from another SO post.

```
    @echo off 
REM create empty file:
break>R1.txt
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
REM prevent empty lines by adding line numbers (find /v /n "")
REM parse the file, taking the second token (*, %%b) with delimiters
REM ] (to eliminate line numbers) and space (to eliminate leading spaces)
for /f "tokens=1,* delims=] " %%a in ('find /v /n "" ^<PXZP_SND_XZ01_GFT10553.dat') do (
  call :sub1 "%%b"
  REM write the string without quotes:
  REM removing the qoutes from the string would make the special chars poisonous again
  >>PXZP_SND_XZ01_GFT10553.dat echo(!s:"=!
)

REM Show the written file:
type PXZP_SND_XZ01_GFT10553.dat 
goto :eof

:sub1
set S=%*
REM do 13 times (adapt to your Needs):
for /l %%i in (1,1,13) do (
  REM replace "space qoute" with "quote" (= removing the last space
  set S=!S: "=|!
)
goto :eof
```

Can someone help me here? Example of my text file:

```
96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII               96860471/971 BBBB HAWAII               96861471/971 CCCC HAWAII               96863471/971 DDDD HAWAII
```

Comment: The `for /F` loop cannot handle lines longer than about 8190 characters...

Comment: How do I get around that problem? I am planning on using the converted file in SSIS which knows how to handle the | delimiter.

Comment: Does any `|` occur in the original file too?

Comment: Nope. Just \ and /

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use appropiate tools.

```
Set Inp = wscript.Stdin
Set Outp = wscript.Stdout
Outp.Write Replace(Inp.ReadAll, "             ", "|")
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo "C:\Replace13Spaces.vbs" < "c:\folder\inputfile.txt" > "C:\Folder\Outputfile.txt"
```

Using Regular expressions to replace 2 or more spaces with a bar.

```
Set Inp = wscript.Stdin
Set Outp = wscript.Stdout
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Outp.Write regEx.Replace(Inp.ReadAll, "|")
```

There are two  other ways to handle this.

1. Like the first way is to `replace` multiple times from the longest to shortest number of predifined spaces. IE 13, 10, 8 or 5 spaces.
2. `Split` the sting on 2 spaces. `Filter` the array to exclude blank array elements. Then `Join` the array with `|` as the delimiter.

Comment: I am getting an error "outp.writeall object doesnt support this property or method". Not sure what's wrong here

Comment: It's been edited. That what you get for not looking at help, even though I had it open.

Comment: Just a follow up question on this. There are other variable lengths of blank spaces in there (8 spaces and 10 spaces). How do I handle those on this script?

Comment: Can you describe the spaces better. IE is there always an allowed 1 space (like between words) and never more.

Comment: For example 96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII               96860471/971 BBBB HAWAII has space between 971 and AAAA (or BBBB). But the space between Hawaii and 96860471/971 can either be 13, 10, 8 or 5 blank spaces. But the text would usually fit the pattern "96859471/971 AAAA HAWAII"

Answer (score 4):

The [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) cannot handle lines longer than about 8190 characters. However, there is a way to read files with longer lines: using [`set /P`](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) in a loop, together with [input redirection `<`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html); `set /P` reads at most 1023 characters, unless a line-break or the end of the file is encountered; executing it multiple times for the same open (input-redirected) file handle allows to read very long lines in portions of 1023 characters since `set /P` does not reset the file pointer.

Another challenge is to return (echo) very long lines, which is not possible with the [`echo` command](https://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) again because of the line limitation of about 8190 characters (which applies to command lines and variable contents). Also here block-wise processing helps: firstly, get an end-of-file character (EOF, ASCII 0x1A); then take a text/string portion, append an EOF and write the result to a temporary file  using `echo` (which appends a line-break), together with [output redirection `>`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html); next copy the file onto itself using [`copy`](https://ss64.com/nt/copy.html), but read it in ASCII text mode to discard the EOF and everything after (hence the line-break previously appended by `echo`) and write it in binary mode to get an exact copy of the resulting data; lastly, type out the file content using [`type`](https://ss64.com/nt/type.html).

The following script makes use of these techniques (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedexpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPUT=.\PXZP_SND_XZ01_GFT10553.dat" & rem // (this is the input file)
set "_OUTPUT=.\R1.txt" & rem // (set to `con` to display the result on the console)
set "_TEMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (specifies a temporary file)
set "_SEARCH=     " & rem // (this is the string to be found)
set "_REPLAC=|"     & rem // (this is the replacement string)
set "_LTRIM=#"      & rem // (set to something to left-trim sub-strings)
(set _LF=^
%= blank line =%
) & rem // (this block stores a new-line character in a variable)
rem // This stores an end-of-file character in a variable:
for /F %%E in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo 0x1A"') do set "_EOF=%%E"

rem /* The input file is going to be processed in a sub-routine,
rem    which accesses the file content via input redirection `<`: */
< "%_INPUT%" > "%_OUTPUT%" call :PROCESS

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
    rem // Reset variables that store a partial string to be processed and a separator:
    set "PART=" & set "SEP="
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:READ
    rem /* At this point 1023 characters are read from the input file at most, until
    rem    a line-break or the end of the file is encountered:*/
    set "NEW=" & set /P NEW=""
    rem // The read characters are appended to a string buffer that will be processed:
    set "PART=!PART!!NEW!"
    rem /* Skip processing when the string buffer is empty, which is the case when the end
    rem    of the file has already been reached: */
:LOOP
    if defined PART (
        rem /* Make the search string accessible as a `for` meta-variable reference in
        rem    to not have to use normal (immediate) `%`-expansion, which could cause
        rem    trouble with some special characters under some circumstances: */
        for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%K in ("!_SEARCH!") do (
            rem /* Try to split the string buffer at the first search string and store the
            rem    portion at the right, using sub-string substitution: */
            set "RIGHT=!PART:*%%K=!"
            rem /* Check whether the split was successful, hence whether a search string
            rem    even occurred in the string buffer; if not, jump back and read more
            rem    characters; otherwise (when the end of the file was reached) clear the
            rem    right portion and continue processing: */
            if "!RIGHT!"=="!PART!" if not defined NEW (set "RIGHT=") else goto :READ
            rem /* Clear the variable that will receive the portion left to the first
            rem    occurrence of the search string in the string buffer; then replace each
            rem    occurrence in the string buffer by a new-line character: */
            set "LEFT=" & set ^"PART=!PART:%%K=^%_LF%%_LF%!^"
            rem /* Iterate over all lines of the altered string buffer, which is now a
            rem    multi-line string, then get the first line, which constitutes the
            rem    portion at the left of the first search string; the (first) line is
            rem    preceded by an `_` just for it not to appear blank, because `for /F`
            rem    skips over empty lines; this character is removed later: */
            for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%L in (^"_!PART!^") do (
                rem // Execute the loop body only for the first iteration:
                if not defined LEFT (
                    rem /* Store the (augmented) left portion with delayed expansion
                    rem    disabled in order not to get trouble with `!` in the string: */
                    setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion & set "LEFT=%%L"
                    rem // Enable delayed expansion to be able to safely echo the string:
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                    rem /* Write to a temporary file the output string, which consists of
                    rem    a replacement string (except for the very first time), the left
                    rem    portion with the preceding `_` removed and an end-of-file
                    rem    character; a line-break is automatically appended by `echo`: */
                    > "!_TEMPF!" echo(!SEP!!LEFT:~1!%_EOF%
                    rem /* Copy the temporary file onto itself, but remove the end-of-file
                    rem    character and everything after, then type the file content;
                    rem    this is a safe way of echoing a string without a line-break: */
                    > nul copy /Y /A "!_TEMPF!" + nul "!_TEMPF!" /B & type "!_TEMPF!"
                    rem /* Restore the environment present at the beginning of the loop
                    rem    body, then ensure the left portion not to appear empty: */
                    endlocal & endlocal & set "LEFT=_"
                )
            )
            rem // If specified, left-trim the right portion, so remove leading spaces:
            if defined _LTRIM (
                for /F "tokens=* eol=  delims= " %%T in ("!RIGHT!_") do (
                    for /F delims^=^ eol^= %%S in (^""!NEW!"^") do (
                        endlocal & set "NEW=%%~S" & set "RIGHT=%%T"
                    )
                    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion & set "RIGHT=!RIGHT:~,-1!"
                )
            )
            rem // Set the replacement string now to skip it only for the first output:
            set "SEP=!_REPLAC!"
            rem /* Move the right portion into the string buffer; if there is still some
            rem    amount of text left, jump back to find more occurrences of the search
            rem    string; if not, jump back and read more characters, unless the end of
            rem    the file has already been reached: */
            set "PART=!RIGHT!" & if defined PART (
                if defined NEW if "!PART:~1024!"=="" goto :READ
                goto :LOOP
            ) else if defined NEW goto :READ
        )
    )
    endlocal
    rem // Clean up the temporary file:
    del "%_TEMPF%"
    exit /B
```

The following restrictions exist:

- the string portions between two consecutive search strings (= 5 × <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in the above approach) must be shorter than about 8190 characters;
- the search string must not be empty, must not begin with `!`, `*`, `~` and must not contain `=`;
- the replace string must not contain `!`;

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The one that I accepted does the job for me. But I appreciate you taking the time to write a response so that it helps someone.

Comment: You're welcome! No need to apologise for accepting somebody else's answer, the decision is totally up to you. (I actually enjoyed taking the challenge of finding a way around some limitations of `cmd`...)