# Insert a pipe delimiter after every 39 characters

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vbscript, ssis, fixed-width

I [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55503031/need-to-replace-13-blank-spaces-from-1-very-long-line-of-text-file) asked the question where I was requiring to remove the blank spaces and replace the one with 13 spaces with a pipe delimiter. I now have a different file with 1 line of very long text in which I need to insert a pipe "|" delimiter after every 39 characters. Sample of the text that I am trying to work with:

```
000/042 BS CALIFORNIA             90001000/042 BS CALIFORNIA             90002000/042 BS CALIFORNIA             90003000/042 BS CALIFORNIA             90004000/042 BS CALIFORNIA
```

I am intending to write a batch file that can do this since I wont be able to load it to any sql server without preprocessing it with SSIS and the delimiters in place. Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
The code that replaced the blank spaces and made the file easy to work with is as below:

```
Set Inp = wscript.Stdin
Set Outp = wscript.Stdout
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\s{2,}"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Outp.Write regEx.Replace(Inp.ReadAll, "|")
```

I am not sure how to modify this so that a pipe delimiter is placed after every 39 characters.

Comment: Strange that you cannot load a fixed text file into your database.  My DB teams does it every day for me with SSIS packages.

Comment: Thank you squashman. Maybe I am bit inept at SSIS too I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Set Inp = wscript.Stdin
Set Outp = wscript.Stdout
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "(.{39,39})"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Global = True
Outp.Write regEx.Replace(Inp.ReadAll, "$1|")
```

http://download.microsoft.com/download/winscript56/Install/5.6/W982KMeXP/EN-US/scrdoc56en.exe

Is the VBScript help file. Look up the `pattern` property. `.` any character except newline, minimum 39 and maximum 39, `$1` replace with what we found plus a pipe.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to all for taking a look at this question. I am posting the solution that I found was sufficient for me. The original intention was to insert a pipeline delimiter after every 39 characters. But I was thinking in a different direction. I can accomplish the same task with SSIS Flat File source where I select the Format option as "Fixed width" and load the data as needed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution based on the code from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55505914) to [your original question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55503031). The following script makes again use of the same techniques to overcome the line length limitations usually applicable for batch files (see all the explanatory `rem` remarks in the code):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedexpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPUT=.\PXZP_SND_XZ01_GFT10553.dat" & rem // (this is the input file)
set "_OUTPUT=.\R1.txt" & rem // (set to `con` to display the result on the console)
set "_TEMPF=%TEMP%\%~n0_%RANDOM%.tmp" & rem // (specifies a temporary file)
set /A "_FIX=39" & rem // (this specifies the fixed width)
set "_INSERT=|"  & rem // (this is the insertion string)
rem // This stores an end-of-file character in a variable:
for /F %%E in ('forfiles /P "%~dp0." /M "%~nx0" /C "cmd /C echo 0x1A"') do set "_EOF=%%E"

rem /* The input file is going to be processed in a sub-routine,
rem    which accesses the file content via input redirection `<`: */
< "%_INPUT%" > "%_OUTPUT%" call :PROCESS

endlocal
exit /B


:PROCESS
    rem // Reset variables that store a partial string to be processed and a separator:
    set "PART=" & set "SEP="
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
:READ
    rem /* At this point 1023 characters are read from the input file at most, until
    rem    a line-break or the end of the file is encountered:*/
    set "NEW=" & set /P NEW=""
    rem // The read characters are appended to a string buffer that will be processed:
    set "PART=!PART!!NEW!"
:LOOP
    rem // Check whether or not the string buffer is empty:
    if defined PART (
        rem // String buffer is not empty, so split it in two parts using the fixed width:
        set "LEFT=!PART:~,%_FIX%!" & set "RIGHT=!PART:~%_FIX%!"
    ) else (
        rem /* String buffer is empty, hence reset both left and right string portions;
        rem    this step is necessary since splitting an empty string is not possible: */
        set "LEFT=" & set "RIGHT="
    )
    rem /* Jump back to read more characters in case the right string portion is empty,
    rem    unless the end of the file has already been reached, hence no more are left: */
    if not defined RIGHT if defined NEW goto :READ
    rem /* Skip processing when the left string portion is empty, which is the case when
    rem    no more data are left, so when the end of the file has already been reached: */
    if defined LEFT (
        rem /* Write to a temporary file the output string, which consists of an insertion
        rem    string (except for the very first time), the left string portion and an
        rem    end-of-file character; a line-break is automatically appended by `echo`: */
        > "!_TEMPF!" echo(!SEP!!LEFT!%_EOF%
        rem /* Copy the temporary file onto itself, but remove the end-of-file character
        rem    and everything after, then type the file content; this is a safe way of
        rem    echoing a string without a trailing line-break: */
        > nul copy /Y /A "!_TEMPF!" + nul "!_TEMPF!" /B & type "!_TEMPF!"
        rem // Set the insertion string now to skip it only for the first output:
        set "SEP=!_INSERT!"
        rem // Move the right string portion into the string buffer:
        set "PART=!RIGHT!"
        rem // Jump back to process the updated string buffer, hence to split it again:
        goto :LOOP
    )
    endlocal
    rem // Clean up the temporary file:
    del "%_TEMPF%"
    exit /B
```

Note that the given fixed width must be a positive number less than about 8190 characters.